# An unexpected value of \clubpenalty

Tags: page-breaking, widows-orphans

In the following MWE, `\clubpenalty` has the expected default value of 150 at the begin of the document. However, a combination of a) a `\section` b) a paragraph c) a `quote` environment – in this particular sequence – will result in a `\clubpenalty` of 10000 (i.e. no orphans are allowed from this point forward). Leaving out any of these three elements will produce the expected value of 150 for `\clubpenalty`. Why is this the case?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Clubpenalty: \the\clubpenalty\ (should be 150)

% Removing either a) the \section or b) the paragraph following it
%     or c) the "quote" environment following it will produce
%     the expected value of 150 for \clubpenalty
\section{A section}

Some text.

\begin{quote}
Some text inside a \texttt{quote} environment.
\end{quote}

Clubpenalty: \the\clubpenalty\ (should be 150)

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm the one that reported that bug. I discovered it while typesetting something using the `mwart` class (which is derived from article); I thought it is a mwart-specific bug. Marcin Woliński, who is the author of mwart, sent me a patch then; if nothing else works, I'll look into it and post it here (but I don't have too much time for that, so I can't do it now and don't want to do it unless someone *really* needs it).

Comment: It would be nice to see that patch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that this hack seems to work, at least if the problematic environment is based on `list`:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\endtrivlist{\aftergroup\@restoreclubpenalty}
\def\@restoreclubpenalty{\clubpenalty\@clubpenalty}
\makeatother
```

Comment: The definition of `\@item` includes the code snippet `\if@nobreak
  \@nobreakfalse
  \clubpenalty \@M
\else
  \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
  \everypar{}%
\fi`. According to `source2e`, "[t]his code is intended to prevent a page break after the first line of an item that comes immediately after a section title". I don't know if this feature is affected by your "hack", but the latter is good enough for me.

Comment: The hack will set the `\clubpenalty` *after* the list environment (because of `\aftergroup`); that code in `\@item` will only set the `\clubpenalty` *inside* the list environment, which is good, but the group ending will make TeX forget it.

Answer (score 10):

I would say it is a bug. It also already reported (but neither analyzed nor solved): http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/4065

Rougly I would say that the problem is that in a list (quote is list) the `\item` doesn't start a paragraph and so the `everypar` trickery of the list and the section clash.

Comment: I've reminded the other members of the LaTeX3 Project about this. I avoid doing LaTeX2e bug fixes (much too complex!), but perhaps someone else will feel more inclined to take a look.

Comment: A fix for this problem was added 2015 to the LaTeX kernel (late but eventually it happened)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the delay.  Since my previous answer was converted into a comment, and AFAIK I can't include TeX code in comments, I paste Marcin Woliński's patch I mentioned here (I don't have time to analyze it now, just pasting it):

```
\def\@doendpe{\@endpetrue
  \clubpenalty\@clubpenalty
  \def\par{\@restorepar\everypar{}\par\@endpefalse}%
  \everypar{{\setbox\z@\lastbox}\everypar{}\@endpefalse}%
}
```