# eledmac two column footnote balancing

Tags: footnotes, two-column, eledmac

I wonder how to influence the column balancing algorithm `eledmac.sty` is using for twocol footnotes (which is, as far as I understand, the `\rigidbalance` command from The TeXbook p 398.

In the following MWE, one line of the left footnote is broken to the second column – which is plausible to make the columns balanced. However if, for some reasons, I don't want this break and would rather prefer unbalanced colums in this case, how can I do this?

[image]

There are two strange observations:

1. Even if I use very high values such as `\widowpenalty=4000` and `\interlinepenalty=4000` in the foonote, this does not influence the behavior. Only setting either of them to 9999 *or* setting both of them to values adding up to 9999 makes a change. Is there anything wrong with the penalty counting? See first part of MWE.
2. *If* I use e.g. `\interlinepenalty=9999` or `\widowpenalty=6000` and `\interlinepenalty=6000` (adding to >9999), strangely the left footnote is broken one line earlier, resulting in 2 lines too much in the right colum. (See second part of MWE). The desirable and the natural behavior instead would be not breaking the left foonote and having 2 lines too much in the *left* column.

[image]

Doesn't all this indicate that the penalty system is not really working here?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\foottwocolX{A}
\def\footnote#1{\footnoteA{#1}}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Test\footnote{%
Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla
bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla
Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla
bla bla Bla bla bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla
% This does not help:  Removing these settings has same result. 
\widowpenalty=4000
\interlinepenalty=4000
} 
Test\footnote{%
Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla 
Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla 
} 
\newpage

Test\footnote{%
Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla
bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla
Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla
bla bla Bla bla bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla
\interlinepenalty=9999
} 
Test\footnote{%
Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla 
Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla 
} 
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** The MWE I gave is a reduced version trying to imitate strange behavior that happens in real life situations. In the following two cases, the columns are unbalanced (or badly balanced) even *without* any manual intervention by manual penalty settings:

[image]

Or:

[image]

Comment: good question. For now, I have now idea. The two columns mechanism of eledmac was implemtend by the author of ledmac, not by me.

Comment: It seems the problem is not specific to eledmac but due to a kernel bug. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241549/what-is-section-and-itemize-doing-to-the-penalty-system-problem-with-eledmac 
and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23062/an-unexpected-value-of-clubpenalty

Comment: yes I saw. I am very glad the bug is not of eledmac.